# PostgreSQL to get data by email irrespective of the minor difference in domain name

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a scenario where authentication is done by the 3rd party and we store the records in our database ie. postgreSQL.

For Example:

| email_id | details | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa124@domain.com | some details | aaa124 |
| aaa124@ex.domain.com | some details | aaa124 |

What I want is to extract all the recores by email Id only irrespective of the minor differences in the domain name changes. As they treat domain.com and ex.domain.com as same.

I have tried

```
SELECT * FROM table where  (
email_id like 'aaa124%'
and 
email_id like '%domain.com'
);
```

but looking for some optimal solution or regex etc.

Note : A user can be registered with multiple domains as well. so need to filter by domain also.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried SELECT * FROM table where  (
email_id like 'aaa124%'
and 
email_id like '%domain.com'
);

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz added the same query in the question itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `LIKE` clauses, like this:

```sql
select * from testing
WHERE email_id LIKE 'aaa124@%domain.com';
```

Output:

```
aaa124@domain.com
aaa124@ex.domain.com
```

Here is a [db <> fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=0fe44cf2d79433c06bb828369c5f0d51) in action.

Comment: Thanks @MushifAliNawaz.. That solves my problem

Comment: @Priyanka I am glad that it helped you. Please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want `split_part()`?

```
select split_part(email, '@', 1) as email_name,
       split_part(email, '@', 2) as domain
from t;
```

Comment: This would separate the email_name and domain and at last I will have to use 2 where clauses to compare the combination. Also the comparison will be with domain will be complicated. In case the email id passed is aaa124@ex.domain.com. In this case, 1st record will not be fetched as it contains only domain.com after @

Comment: @Priyanka . . . Your question is:  "I want is to extract all the recores by email Id only irrespective of the domain changes. "  This extracts the email without the domain, which appears to be what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
select * from yourTable where email like 'aaa124@%';
```

This will select all users with the email aaa124 for all domains. You may want to use ilike instead of like if you also want match different cases of the email address.

Comment: a user can be registered with multiple domains as well. so need to filter by domain also..